# Adding styling: json2html node module

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I wrote a basic script that reads a JSON file and converts it to an HTML table using json2html. I then email this table using nodemailer.

**The code works to send the table in an email. However, I would like to add some styling to the table and am yet to find a good solution.**

Below is the code for my HTML Table creation:

```
    var jsonText = fs.readFileSync('file.json').toString();
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonText);

    var tmpl = "<td>${firstName}</td><td>${lastName}</td><td>${email}</td><td>${skills}</td><td>${linkedin}</td><td>${github}</td>"
    var transform = {'tag':'tr','html':tmpl};

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (data.skills) {
            data.skills = data.skills.join(',' + ' ');
        }
    })

    var resp = "<table>" + json2html.transform(data,transform) + "</table>";
```

Here is sendmail portion of my nodemailer code for reference:

```
    transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'email@gmail.com',
    to: 'email@gmail.com',
    subject: 'TEST',
    html: resp
});
```

Comment: not very difficult to throw in some inline style for a fairly simple piece of html. Usually the easiest way to consistently style email anyway

Comment: @charlietfl okay, I'll add some inline styling and repost once it is complete. Thanks for the help.